# Gratis, dedicated, Windows 10 PDF to image tool

Tags: gratis, pdf, windows-10, document-converter, jpg

There are a few questions asking for PDF to image conversion. Answers tend to recommend something that *can* do it, but was not built to do it, such as Libre Office or InkScape.

I am looking for a fully gratis (no trial periods or watermarks) Windows 10 tool which is ***dedicated*** to processing PDFs and only that.

Must have:

- PDF to image

Nice to have, as a bonus:

- other PDF tools, such as OCR, editing, text export, watermark, combine multiple files into one, split one file into multiple (by page), recover lost password, etc. The more the merrier.

Comment: What would be the benefit of such a tool over Libre Office or similar? Do you want to automate something? Does it need to run from command line?

Comment: Sorry, while I reazlie that other apps could do it, this is just the way that my mid works. I want adedicated tool (Ordnung muss sein). If I must give a reason, then it is that a dedicated PDF -> JPG app is likely to have more PDF manipulation functionality than a non-decicated one, and one day I might need that functionality, even if I do not neeed it now.

Comment: I also prefer tools dedicated for a job :-) Just wanted to make sure there are no hidden requirements. Are you German? Ist mir noch nie aufgefallen.

Comment: A tricky question. I spent more of my adult life in Germany than in any of the other 15 countries (on 3 continents) where I have lived & worked. So, my attitude, opinions and feelings are probably more German than anything else. Btw, I like the subtle way you asked "Are you German? Ist mir noch nie aufgefallen", carefully avoiding the personal personal pronoun in German :-) `mein Name ist Mawg - und ich heisse "Du"` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Any PDF to JPG](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/any-pdf-to-jpg-pdf-to-jpeg-pdf-to-png-pdf-to-images-converter/9ngv3rrb3zk2#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) should do the job.

Comment: Welcome aboard. I am guessing rom your user name that this might be your tool? I so, we prefer that you state so. If not - maybe you just like converting :-) - please accent my apologies. In either case, thanks. You have helped me, and others who will read this question in future. Upvote, and the answer

Comment: Not my tool as I don´t have developed it, but I am familiar with such tools since have a lot to do with converting from one format to an other.

Comment: The you have a great user name:-)  Welcom aboard, we look forward to your help in future